# Where is "conda env" documented?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am wondering why the official documentation of [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html) does not mention anything about the command `conda env`?

That makes me wonder if it would be possible to do every operation of `conda env` with the commands listed [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html) and which one is recommended to use in practice. Right now I would assume that `conda env` creates an easy way to manipulate and work with conda environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the `conda env` commands are not similarly documented is historical.

Namely, after `conda` was developed, others then developed [an add-on package called `conda-env`](https://github.com/conda-archive/conda-env) that provided some convenience methods for operating on *whole* environments rather than package operations *within* environments. Eventually, the `conda-env` package was integrated directly into the `conda` package, but apparently there was never any systematic effort to unify the documentation. Instead, most of the high-level documentation on using `conda env` commands is found under the ["*Managing environments*" section](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) of the Conda documentation.

As an end user, I typically use `conda env` for creating (from YAML), archiving/serializing (to YAML), and deleting whole environments.

More directly, the documentation for `conda env` is consulted with

```bash
$ conda env --help
usage: conda-env [-h] {create,export,list,remove,update,config} ...

positional arguments:
  {create,export,list,remove,update,config}
    create              Create an environment based on an environment file
    export              Export a given environment
    list                List the Conda environments
    remove              Remove an environment
    update              Update the current environment based on environment file
    config              Configure a conda environment

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit.
```

and documentation of individual subcommands can be similarly consulted with  `conda env <subcommand> --help`.